# Asymmetric quantum eraser: Contradiction between direct and indirect measurements?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-eraser

I studied the experience of Kim et al. (1999) that specialists are familiar with :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed-choice_quantum_eraser

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9903047

I propose here a modification of this experiment and this modification leads me to contradictory theoretical experimental results:

To begin with, I simplify the original experiment by removing the BSa and BSb beamsplitters, as well as the D3 and D4 detectors, to focus only on the part of the device likely to exhibit interference :

[image]

So far, so good:

By establishing a link between the detections made in D0 and the detections made respectively in D1 and D2 thanks to the coincidence counter, I am able to "reconstruct" a posteriori the 2 subsets (2 interference patterns out of phase by 180°) whose sum only gives a fog pattern (the 2 patterns compensate each other and the direct visualization of an interference pattern is impossible in D0).

Note that in D1 and D2, if I had lenses L1, L2 instead, and screens S1 and S2, I wouldn't directly see any interference with entangled photons either.
These interferences would be visible only with non-entangled "classical" photons from a laser whose light would be projected only into the interferometer.
This is basically impossible with entangled photons.

Ok, now I complicate the previous diagram:

By slightly tilting the mirror Mb on the one hand and the beam splitter BSc on the other hand to the left (direction of the arrows), I obtain the following configuration :

[image]

In the upper part of the quantum eraser (asymmetrical), the 2 possible paths coincide in D2. As in the 1st diagram, by establishing a link between the detections made in D0 and in D2 thanks to the coincidence counter, I am able to reconstruct a posteriori the subset corresponding to D2.
As D2 can't discern which path the photon is taking, this subset corresponds to an interference signal.

As above, if I had an L2 lens and an S2 screen instead of D2, I wouldn't directly see any interference with entangled photons either.
Also as above, these interferences would be visible with non-entangled "classical" photons from a laser whose light would be projected only into the interferometer.

In the lower part of the asymmetric quantum eraser, this time I place 2 detectors D1 and D'1 (instead of just one) beyond the crossing point of the two beams.

By establishing a link between the detections made in D0 and the detections made respectively in D1 and D'1 thanks to the coincidence counter, I am able to "reconstruct" a posteriori the 2 subsets corresponding respectively to D1 and D'1( two meaningless fog patterns) which add up to a meaningless fog pattern :
This makes sense since thanks to D1 and D'1, this time I can know "which path" a photon took.

**This time we have a problem:**

The predictions of quantum mechanics are formal, there are never any directly visible interferences (as before) in D0. If so, FTL communication would become possible.

Except that here I can reconstruct 3 subsets a posteriori:

A subset giving a fog pattern for photons captured in D1
A subset giving a fog pattern for photons captured in D'1
A subset giving an interference pattern for photons captured in D2

**If I sum these 3 subsets**, (supposed to give the complete set) I get something that is no longer a simple fog pattern but a **slight interference pattern superimposed on a fog background, this which is completely different!**

So, what I am supposed to observe directly in D0 (all signals = fog) is no longer compatible with all the signals reconstructed after correlations between the D0 detector and the 3 detectors D1, D'1 and D2 (**I don't have a mere "fog" but "something else" good discernible from a mere fog**).

There is no 4th subset which can "cancel" the interference pattern reconstructed thanks to D2 here, since **we only work with 3 photons** having different behaviors.

What is going on?
Where is the error?

Comment: I don't even know what "coincidence" for non-entangled photons is supposed to mean. It's just random, completely independent emission processes. Can you get interference patterns for those? Absolutely, but you don't have to consider anything this complex. A double slit will do, so will a pair of mirrors. Where do these patterns come from? Maxwell, which is the mean field theory of the quantized electromagnetic field.

Comment: Absolutely.
I completely agree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a very small part of the photons from the laser pump will become a pair of entangled photons at the output of the BBO crystal (about 4 pairs per million).

The other photons (the majority) are removed from the device.
A part of these entangled photons is sent into the device.

With entangled photons, we will NEVER observe direct interferences, neither in the first diagram, nor in the second.

I found the cause of the problem raised and QM isn't even the cause of the problem, it's a basic problem of sets and subsets:

There is an error in the initial assumptions:

The error is to think that one can reconstruct an interference pattern with D2 in the second diagram.
It takes **TWO** subsets representing the correlations of interference measurements to reconstruct these **TWO** subsets (as in the first diagram).

In the second diagram, there is **only ONE** set representing in reality **all the correlations** of interference measurements :

We can't therefore split this single "subset" (rather the total) into two interference patterns, a first and a second phase shifted by 180°:

This set representing the totality, these two patterns appear confused when one tries to reconstruct the pattern, and what is reconstructed is in fact a pattern of fog.

The totality of the reconstructed patterns thanks to D2, D1 and D'1 is therefore:
fog + fog + fog = fog (what we observe directly).

There is therefore no contradiction between what is directly observed and what can be reconstructed a posteriori with the coincidence counter.

More simply :

Schematically, with 100 points in D0 :

In the first diagram, we have 50 points in D1 and 50 points in D2.
We can "color" in yellow 50 points in D0 thanks to D1 and "color" in green 50 points in D0 thanks to D2.
We will reconstruct 2 interference patterns (one yellow and one green).

In the second diagram, we have 100 points in D2 : we can only use one color and all the points of the same color don't show anything.
(this amounts to erasing the yellow and green forming two distinct patterns of interference to use only "gray" and no longer distinguish anything at all except fog).

Answer (score -2):

I have also given thought to the above QE experiment and have written a few answers here on PSE.  In general if we follow Feynman and Dirac logic .... that every photon has its own path, and then further with the Feynman path integral ... many paths are considered and the ones that tend to be most probable are the ones that have length that are integer multiples of the wavelength ... we can draw conclusions not only about the DSE but also the above QE question as well.

A photon is the energy transfer part in the EM field, but just as important are the "virtual photons" i.e. the force carriers.  One can say that even before emission of a real photon the EM field has already been active ... the EM field considers all the electrons in the apparatus .... the excited ones probably having the most effect.

All the optics/detectors/filters/crystals/slits could be taken into account be these excited electron virtual forces .... thus the path of the photon is determined.  In general the QE experiment was shown not to provide faster than light communication.  When you measure coincidences its because all the paths (including the single original photon and the down converted pair) satisfied the path integral and transmission was possible.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Only a small portion of the photons from the laser will become a pair in the crystal, and an even a smaller portion of these pairs will find their way thru the prism to the detectors.  These rare photon pairs will always "interfere", that means the EM field (virtual) has bee affected by the entire apparatus, including the double slits, which is why we eventually observe the pattern with real photons/detectors.

Comment: I'm probably not understanding your apparatus entirely,  but if you put a deflector in a DSE after the slits to shift the pattern around ... yes you will start to see a blur .... but that does not mean lack of interference.